# C++ Methods of store type_info objects doesn't work

Tags: c++, object, typeid, typeinfo

I'm having some trouble understanding the correspondance between the return type of `typeid` and actual `type_info` objects which seems to work differently from usual objects. For example, I can do...

```
std::cout << typeid(int).name() << std::endl;
```

...and get a decent behaviour form the program... but this won't compile...

```
std::type_info a(int);
std::cout << a.name() << std::endl;
```

Compiler outputs:

```
type_info.cpp: In function 'int main()':
type_info.cpp:6:17: error: request for member 'name' in 'a', which is of non-class type 'std::type_info(int)'
```

...nor can I do...

```
if(a == typeid(int)) {/*Do something*/ } //Looong error message
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe `std::type_info a(typeid(int));`?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work since copy constructor of type_info is private...

Comment: Ah, true. Then `const std::type_info &a(typeid(int));`? Or if you prefer: `const std::type_info *a(&typeid(int));`?

Comment: When asking about code that does not compile, please always include the _full actual compiler output_ you are getting, _verbatim_. Since you don't understand the error, you can't otherwise be sure you transcribed all important clues it contains.

Comment: Jan Hudec: Yes! Will remember and added one of the compilier errors here rodrigo: Got it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off, vexing parse:

```
std::type_info a(int);
```

`a` is a function (taking `int` and returning `std::type_info`).

Second, `std::type_info` is not copyable, so you cannot store it by value. You can use a reference if it suits your needs:

```
const std::type_info &a(typeid(int));
```

If you need to actually store `std::type_info` objects (as if) "by value," use [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) instead; it was designed for this:

```
std::type_index a(typeid(int));
std::cout << a.name() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Gotcha... ok so is there a reason why std::type_info a((int)) doesn't work then? I mean than it won't be parsed as a function and we don't use its assignment operator or copy constructor, right?

Comment: @fast-reflexes It's syntactic nonsense - you're missing a `typeid` operator in there. `std::type_info` has no special rules in the grammar of the lanuage, so syntactically, it's exactly the same as `std::string a((int));`. And as soon as you add `typeid`, you're looking to copy from the operator's return value.

Comment: Ah yeah, of course, there is no reason to believe that type_info has a constructor that takes a type (in fact, that's not even possible so you're right of course.. it IS nonsense!)

Answer (score 3):

`std::type_info` is neither copy-constructible nor copy-assignable. Thus you can't do stuff like `std::type_info a = typeid(...)`.

```
const std::type_info &someTypeId(typeid(someType));
```

You can also store a pointer to a `std::type_info` object, because typeid returns a lvalue.

There is also [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) in case you want to use `std::type_info` objects as a key in containers. It is essentially a thin wrapper around a pointer to a `std::type_info`. `std::type_index` is a C++11 feature.